# Keybind Shortcuts - Opening other views from MainView - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a bidding program to give customers quotes. I'm using WPF + MVVM

What I would like to do is to be able to create a shortcut (Ctrl+O) from the main page directly to the view that enables me to select which bid I want to open.

I can't imagine it is very difficult, I just seem to be missing something. I've looked for the answer in other threads. It is possible that I have missed it, if I have, please let me know and refer me to where the answer can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have a command you are calling when clicking the button to open the other view you could use an `InputBinding`

Something like this should do the work

```
<Window>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OpenSecondViewCommand}"
                    Modifiers="Control" 
                    Key="O"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
 </Window>
```